# Регистрация типов событий при использовании плагинов

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Приложение использует события (наследники `QEvent`). Каждое событие, как и положено, имеет строго определённый тип - целое число между `QEvent::User` и `QEvent::MaxUser`, получаемое через статическую функцию `QEvent::registerEventType()`.

Типы событий без проблем идентифицируются в методе объекта-приёмника:

```
void MyClass::customEvent(QEvent *event) {
    if(event->type() == MyEventOne::eventType()) {
        MyEventOne *event1 = static_cast<MyEventOne*>(event);
        ...

    } else if(event->type() == MyEventTwo::eventType()) {
        MyEventTwo *event2 = static_cast<MyEventTwo*>(event);
        ...

    } else ...
}
```

Однако проблемы начинаются, как только событие приходит из динамически загруженного плагина. Числовые значения типов одного и того же класса отличаются.

Регистрировать события пробовал двумя способами.

### Способ первый

Файл **myeventone.h**:

```
#include <QtCore/QEvent>

class MyEventOne : public QEvent {
    public:
        static const QEvent::Type &_event_type;

        explicit MyEventOne();

};
```

Файл **myeventone.cpp**:

```
#include "myeventone.h"

const QEvent::Type &MyEventOne::_event_type
    = static_cast<QEvent::Type>(QEvent::registerEventType());

MyEventOne::MyEventOne() : QEvent(_event_type) {}
```

### Способ второй

Файл **myeventone.h**:

```
#include <QtCore/QEvent>

class MyEventOne : public QEvent {
    public:
        static QEvent::Type eventType();

        explicit MyEventOne();

};
```

Файл **myeventone.cpp**:

```
#include <QtCore/QGlobalStatic>

#include "myeventone.h"

Q_GLOBAL_STATIC_WITH_ARGS(int, _g_event_type, (QEvent::registerEventType()))

QEvent::Type MyEventOne::eventType() {
    return static_cast<QEvent::Type>(*_g_event_type);
}

MyEventOne::MyEventOne(): QEvent(MyEventOne::eventType()) {}
```

В обоих случаях, если использую плагин и отправляю из него объект события, то получаю разное числовое значение типа события. При этом файлы класса `MyEventOne` и в плагине, и непосредственно в основной части приложения те же самые.

Мне известно, что у функции `QEvent::registerEventType()` имеется аргумент `hint`, который может выступать в роли подсказки при генерации числового значения для типа события, однако в этом случае удручает необходимость определения таких подсказок (типов событий много) как-то глобально и очень желательно единым списком.

Как можно порешать данную проблему и если без вышеобозначенных подсказок не обойтись, то как их задействовать корректно?

**Дополнение**

Сделал хелперную статическую функцию, которая по имени присваивает константное значение конкретному типу события.

```
int EventHelper::registerEventType(const QString &class_name) {
    if(class_name == QLatin1String("MyEventOne"))
        return QEvent::registerEventType(QEvent::User+1000);
    else if(class_name == QLatin1String("MyEventTwo"))
        return QEvent::registerEventType(QEvent::User+1001);

    return QEvent::registerEventType();
}
```

В итоге при подключении приложения к плагину, события из плагина имеют другое значение типа. Становится очевидно, что происходит перерегистрация события. Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так в динамической библиотеке своя копия статической переменной.

Можно в класс события добавить статический метод с параметром "реестр типов событий"(например, обертку над `std::map<std::string, QEvent::Type>` - имя->тип).

В основной программе создаем Singleton реестра и передаем ссылку/указатель его инстанс в плагин.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Но источник проблемы скорее не в том, что в плагине своя копия статической переменной, а в том, что `QEvent::registerEventType()` вызывается дважды и перерегистрирует тип события на новое значение. А узнать, был  ли уже зарегистрирован тип события или пока ещё нет - возможности, что называется "из коробки", никакой. Нет ли другой возможности, кроме как тащить в плагин инстанс списка наименований и значений типов событий?

Comment: Нужна связь между программой и плагином для синхронизации зарегистрированных типов. Я предложил один вариант, как реализовать такую связь

Comment: Спасибо. Видете, интерес в том, что производится, как я понял, перерегистрация типа при подключении плагина (дполнение в вопросе). То есть инстансу плагина известно, что такое-то значение уже зарезервировано. Нет ли здесь возможности как-то обыграть ситуацию с тем, что если тип уже зарезервирован, то использовать имеющееся значение вместо регистрации нового?

Comment: Так реестр для этого и нужен - если событие не зарегистрировано, то оно в него добавляется, иначе номер берется из реестра.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, я к тому, что если в реестре значения как-то разделяются между приложением и плагином, то получается иррационально вести свою копию реестра по своим типам событий и вносить её из приложения в плагин. Уже есть глобальный реестр, нужно только уточнить, внесли ли в него ранее определённое значение или нет. Если уже внесли, то по константному наименованию типа события (по строке) получим и значение. Но вот к сожалению у `QEvent` нет такого метода. Попробую в исходниках посмотреть, как тролли вообще добиваются разделяемости данных между плагином и программой.

Comment: Возможно прояснит ситуацию статья ["Что такое Pimpl по версии Qt"](https://habrahabr.ru/post/76248/)

Comment: Спасибо. Нет, это немного другое. К тому же если уж static между плагином и приложением не разделяется, то техника указателей на приватные области данных точно не поможет. Я посмотрел в исходнике `QEvent`. Там как-то сделано на атомарных типах данных. Попробую честно свистнуть код и перетащить к себе. Если заработает, то просто добавлю одно условие и получу свой глобальный реестр кастомных типов событий, разделяемый плагином и приложением.

Comment: В общем, работает изъятый код троллей. Вам спасибо ещё раз, что натолкнули на мысль.

Answer (score 1):

Код из исходника `QEvent`, разделяющий реестр пользовательских событий между приложением и плагинами:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

template <size_t N>
struct QBasicAtomicBitField {
    enum {
        BitsPerInt = std::numeric_limits<uint>::digits,
        NumInts = (N + BitsPerInt - 1) / BitsPerInt,
        NumBits = N
    };

    QBasicAtomicInteger<uint> next;
    QBasicAtomicInteger<uint> data[NumInts];

    bool allocateSpecific(int which) {
        QBasicAtomicInteger<uint> &entry = data[which / BitsPerInt];
        const uint old = entry.load();
        const uint bit = 1U << (which % BitsPerInt);
        return !(old & bit) && entry.testAndSetRelaxed(old, old | bit);
    }

    int allocateNext() {
        for(uint i = next.load(); i < NumBits; ++i) {
            if(allocateSpecific(i)) {
                const uint oldNext = next.load();
                next.testAndSetRelaxed(oldNext, qMax(i + 1, oldNext));
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
};

typedef QBasicAtomicBitField<QEvent::MaxUser-QEvent::User+1>
    UserEventTypeRegistry;

static UserEventTypeRegistry userEventTypeRegistry;

static inline int registerEventTypeZeroBased(int id) {
    if(id < UserEventTypeRegistry::NumBits && id >= 0
        && userEventTypeRegistry.allocateSpecific(id))
        return id;

    return userEventTypeRegistry.allocateNext();
}
```

Проверка на то, что событие уже зарегистрировано практически идентична функции регистрации за исключением того, что не производится регистрация нового события:

```
static inline int isEventRegistered(int id) {
    if(id < UserEventTypeRegistry::NumBits && id >= 0
        && userEventTypeRegistry.allocateSpecific(id))
        return id;

    return -1;
}
```

Регистрация нового события или возврат значения уже зарегистрированного:

```
static inline int regEventType(int hint) {
    const int id = QEvent::MaxUser - hint;
    int result = isEventRegistered(id);
    if(result < 0) result = registerEventTypeZeroBased(id);
    return result < 0 ? -1 : QEvent::MaxUser - result;
}
```

Статический метод класса, позволяющий по имени класса получать типы событий, прозрачно регистрируя новые:

```
int EventHelper::registerEventType(const QString &class_name) {
    if(class_name == QLatin1String("MyEventOne"))
        return regEventType(QEvent::User + 1000);

    else if(class_name == QLatin1String("MyEventTwo"))
        return regEventType(QEvent::User + 1001);

    return regEventType(-1);
}
```

Таким образом становится возможно произвести разделение типов событий между приложением и плагинами, не передавая статического списка в эти самые плагины. Всё, получается, будет собрано в одном месте.